# Get Facebook event admin from API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

Given the id of an event, is there a way to get the Facebook ids of the admins of that event through one of Facebook's many API's? The event is public. I can I know you can get the creator of the event but there may be admins other than the creator and I want to get those people as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, You can only retreive a list of current members

[Facebook Developer Manual Thing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.getMembers/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this post: [How to get Events Admin of Facebook event using Graph Api iphone dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807094/how-to-get-events-admin-of-facebook-event-using-graph-api-iphone-dev)

You can try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/admins
```