# How to get Events Admin of Facebook event using Graph Api iphone dev?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can any one help me on that how can i get Admin of events from facebook using graph api, i also search field of event which facebook provided to us but couldn't get admin field, kindly help me on that thanks in advance

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin

Comment: this is for pages of facebook but i need event admin...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{event_id}/admins
```

Comment: Nice catch. Any idea how to do this with FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Using FQL, query the `event` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) and read the creator (id of user who created the event).  More than likely they should be one of the admins for the event.

Comment: Getting the creator is easy.. But there is only one per event.. Any idea how to get **all the admins** using FQL?